# Type annotation for React Higher Order Component using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing a Higher Order Component for my React project using Typescript which is basically a function accepts a React component as an argument and return a new component that wraps around it.

Yet as it works as expected, TS is complaining that "Return type of exported function has or is using private name "Anonymous class".

*Function in question:*

```
export default function wrapperFunc <Props, State> (
    WrappedComponent: typeof React.Component,
) {
    return class extends React.Component<Props & State, {}> {
        public render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...this.state} />;
        }
    };
}
```

The error is reasonable as the returning class of wrapper function is not exported and other module imports this function has no way of knowing what the return value would be. But I cannot declare the return class outside of this function as it requires to wrap a component pass to the outer function.

A trial with explicitly specifying return type `typeof React.Component` like below do suppress this error.

*Function in question with explicit return type:*

```
export default function wrapperFunc <Props, State> (
    WrappedComponent: typeof React.Component,
): typeof React.Component {                     // <== Added this
    return class extends React.Component<Props & State, {}> {
        public render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...this.state} />;
        }
    };
}
```

However, I am not certain about validity of this approach. Is it considered a right approach for tackling this particular error in TypeScript? (Or am I creating unintended side effects elsewhere? Or any better way of doing such?)

(Edit) Change quoted code as per Daniel's suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Type annotation for React Higher Order Component using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499831/type-annotation-for-react-higher-order-component-using-typescript)

The return type `typeof React.Component` is truthful, but not very helpful for users of the wrapped component. It discards information about what props the component accepts.

The React typings provide a handy type for this purpose, `React.ComponentClass`. It’s the type of a class, rather than the type of the component created from that class:

```
React.ComponentClass<Props>
```

(Note that the `state` type isn’t mentioned as it’s an internal detail).

In your case:

```
export default function wrapperFunc <Props, State, CompState> (
    WrappedComponent: typeof React.Component,
): React.ComponentClass<Props & State> {
    return class extends React.Component<Props & State, CompState> {
        public render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...this.state} />;
        }
    };
}
```

However, you’re doing the same thing with the `WrappedComponent` parameter. Based on how you’re using it inside `render`, I’m guessing that it should also be declared:

```
WrappedComponent: React.ComponentClass<Props & State>,
```

But this is wild guess as I assume this is not the complete function (`CompState` isn’t used, and `Props & State` may as well be a single type parameter as it always appears in that combination).

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the detailed answer. I scrubbed the code but failed to clean up unnecessary part. Yes CompState is irrelevant to this question. And I your guess is correct (really appreciate think beyond the question). I modified the question to drop CompState part as that may confuse others in future.

Answer (score 0):

A more appropriate type for the input parameter would be `React.ComponentType`, since it handles stateless components too.

```
type ComponentType<P = {}> = ComponentClass<P> | StatelessComponent<P>
```

Following is an example clarifying its usage.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function <P = {}>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.ComponentClass<P> {
  return class extends React.Component<P> {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
```