# React typescript extending a container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a base class, wrap that in a container, and then extending this within my other components.

Here is a simplified example:

```
let state = new State();
class Base extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

}

const Container = state.connect(
    () => {
        return {

        }
    },
    () => {
        return {

        }
    }
)(Base);

class S extends Container {

}
```

This, however, is returning an error:

```
`error TS2507: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.`.
```

If I extend the `Base` directly, it works fine, but then how would I get access to the state and dispatch actions that I'd put into the container?

**UPDATE**

I created the following interface (omitting templates for simplicity)

```
interface IState {
    connect: (
        mapStateToProps: () => any,
        mapDispatchToProps: () => any,
    ) => (component: typeof React.Component) => typeof React.Component
} 

let state: IState = new State();
```

Now class extension does not throw any error. However, the original `Base` class is never called! Only the constructor of the `Connect` method is called.

The idea here is that I will have an abstract component and container (all the dispatch actions are on the container). And I can then extend this component from my other classes. However, since the container contains all the dispatch actions, then I need to extend the container, not the component.

Comment: MAybe you should declare HOC as special types: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499831/type-annotation-for-react-higher-order-component-using-typescript

Comment: more than 3 questions in the same day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can reuse the value returned by `state.connect()`.

```
let state = new State();
class Base extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
}

class S extends Base {
}

const containerFactory = state.connect(
    () => {
        return {}
    },
    () => {
        return {}
    }
);

const BaseContainer = containerFactory(Base);
const SContainer = containerFactory(S);
```

Comment: Yea I can do that but i want to use it as `class S extends BaseContainer`. The reason is because I am using Typescript so I need to get access to the props of BaseContainer