# How to write type annotation for higher-order component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I wanted to write a [Higher-Order Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) for my react 15.6 project, but I don't know how to write type annotation for it.

I've done some searching

### 1. [The typeof type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/typeof/)

like `typeof Component`?

### 2. the function type

This seems right to me, since a class is actually a function. But should the type of the function be written as `()=>Component<*>`? In the following code, is the use of `any` correct? It made the type "broader".

```
 // @flow
    import React, {type Component} from 'react'

    const faded = (componentKlass:()=>{}) => class FadedWrapper
        extends React.Component<any> {
        //...
    }
```

### 3. See the screenshot

This doesn't look right because we need a class here, but the warning made me wonder what's the `*`(I also present a possible use of it in the #2 above.)?

The warning says "Application of polymorphic type needs . (Can use `*` for inferable ones)"

What I guess is in a case where the param should be an instance of some subclass of `Component`, flow can infer the type.

[image]

### 4. [from TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499831/type-annotation-for-react-higher-order-component-using-typescript?rq=1)

suggests a use of `React.ComponentClass`.

Comment: Does https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/ help?

Comment: Thanks! You are really helpful! I can write an answer when I finish reading, or you can write and I will checkmark it?

Comment: `React.ComponentType` in the doc seems to be missing. Still searching...

Comment: Note that there is a big difference between Flow < 0.53 and newer versions. Make sure the docs or discussions you read are on the same side of that that you use.

Comment: The flow version used is 0.53.1. I raised an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4774) and got the answer. I will write an answer here soon.

Comment: @LShi We are waiting for an answer)

Comment: Hi @TarasYaremkiv, I did post an answer earlier, however flow raised error when I use the HOC(Higher Order Function), then I fixed it but still think it's not a perfect solution. So I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4774), still waiting for responses. I will now undelete my original answer and add a fix/note.

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv just updated again, I found that it's better, if not compulsory (in my case it is) to use capitalized name for component.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Paolo Moretti's pointing [the link](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/hoc/) in his comment, a solution has come up.

```
// @flow
import React from 'react';
import type { ComponentType } from 'react';
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import './faded.css';

export const FirstChild = (props: any) => {
  const children = React.Children.toArray(props.children);
  return children[0] || null;
};

const faded = (ComponentKlass: ComponentType<*>) =>
  class extends React.Component<*> {
    render() {
      return (
        <CSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="fade"
          transitionAppear={false}
          transitionAppearTimeout={1500}
          transitionEnter={true}
          transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
          component={FirstChild}
        >
        {this.props.shouldRender ? 
          <ComponentKlass {...this.props} /> : null}
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
      );
    }
  };

export default faded;
```

It should be noticed that the `ComponentType`should be imported this way: `import type { ComponentType} from 'react'`, since it's not a property of `React` (the default export of 'react'). We can't use it in a way like `React.ComponentType` unless we `import * as React from 'react'`.

I used `componentKlass` instead of `ComponentKlass`, it seems jsx/flow doesn't mind whether we use capitalized name for component name or not. Of course usually it shouldn't. However it will raise an error at runtime, something like:

> Warning: Unknown props onCancel, cities, shouldRender on tag.

(`onCancel` & `cities` are for my decorated component.)